# Landsat 5 image processing

Tags: coordinates, landsat, pixel

I am working with  Landsat 5 images in UTM-WGS84 using the Qgis 2.14 software.
I need to obtain the XY pixel coordinates with their ND and to extract them in an Excel list.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GDAL, try:

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ input.tif output.asc
```